# Using drawRect with a pop over, need to display images

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, popover

in my application I have a class name `playGrid` which contains three objects, an `NSArray` of images named `plays`, and two `NSUIntegers` `rowCount` and `columCount` for the amount of rows and columns in the popover that will be used.

For this example, I have 6 images and I am trying to show them over 2 columns and three rows. I am trying to display these views in a popover. Previously I was able to do this with blocks of colors, but now that I am trying to do with images I am unable to generate the popover correctly. Listed below is my drawRect code for the successful popover that shows the colors.

How would I convert this to work with `UIImage`s instead of the colors?

In the example below, `rowCount` and `columnCount` are 2 and 3 just like the one we are trying to make, but the array is named colors, and contains six `UIColor` items.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
CGRect b = self.bounds;
CGContextRef myContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGFloat columnWidth = b.size.width / columnCount;
CGFloat rowHeight = b.size.height / rowCount;

for (NSUInteger rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rowCount; rowIndex++) {
  for (NSUInteger columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < columnCount; columnIndex++) {
    NSUInteger colorIndex = rowIndex * columnCount + columnIndex;
    UIColor *color = [self.colors count] > colorIndex ? [self.colors objectAtIndex:colorIndex] : [UIColor whiteColor];
      CGRect r = CGRectMake(b.origin.x + columnIndex * columnWidth,
                        b.origin.y + rowIndex * rowHeight,
                        columnWidth, rowHeight);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(myContext, color.CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(myContext, r);


  }
 }
}
```

I know I will not need certain things like the color or the `CGContextSetFillColorWithColor` line, but how do i replace `myContent` with the image, it seems like this is what I would have to do, but I have not been able to successfully do this. Thanks again for your help as I am newer to Objective C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to continue to do drawing into the view using `drawRect:`, I think you just want to use the `drawInRect:` method on `UIImage`.

So:

```
UIImage *image = [plays objectAtIndex:rowIndex * columnCount + columnIndex];
[image drawInRect:r];
```

I've heard the performance of `drawInRect` is not great - but I haven't measured it myself.  Note also that `drawInRect:` scales the image to fit the rect as needed; so visually, the results may not be what you intend.

An alternative is to compose your popover's view in a nib where you could layout your view statically.  If you always want a 2x3 matrix, you could setup your view there with a 2x3 grid of `UIImageView` instances.

**EDIT:** (to clarify that you are drawing images in the rects now, no filling blocks of color)

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGRect b = self.bounds;
    CGContextRef myContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGFloat columnWidth = b.size.width / columnCount;
    CGFloat rowHeight = b.size.height / rowCount;

    for (NSUInteger rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rowCount; rowIndex++) {
        for (NSUInteger columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < columnCount; columnIndex++) {
            CGRect r = CGRectMake(b.origin.x + columnIndex * columnWidth,
                        b.origin.y + rowIndex * rowHeight,
                        columnWidth, rowHeight);
            UIImage *image = [plays objectAtIndex:rowIndex * columnCount + columnIndex];
            [image drawInRect:r];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when adding in the above code, I am just now getting black bars across the rows - no separation for 2 columns either. Is there anything else I would have to change besides adding this in? I am placing this right before the line         CGContextFillRect(myContext, r); - could be that since its fitting them to size that it is showing the black bar - but the images all had white backgrounds so it seems like its not shrinking or scaling them.

Comment: I edited to show the full `drawRect`.  I understood you to say that you no longer wanted the color blocks, so `CGContextFillRect` isn't needed.  Again, if you have a static layout of images, I think you're better off laying this out in a nib with `UIImageView`s  The docs state that `drawInRect` scale the images - (vis-a-vis your last sentence...)